# Using master theorem when there is a constant in the recursive term

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

Is it possible to use the master theorem to find the asymptotic growth of a function of the form:
$$T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}+c)+f(n)$$
Where $c$ is a constant. Can we safely ignore this constant and use the master theorem?

Comment: Not quite ignore, but you can reduce it to the master theorem by a substitution $n\mapsto n+cb/(b-1)$.

Comment: This question is not research-level and therefore off topic here.  I can either migrate it to CS.SE or close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the standard statement of the generally used [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), but the related [Akra-Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) theorem works.